# I want one cell to display some of the characters from another cell

Tags: excel, reference, excel-formula, cell

How do I make a cell show some of the characters of another cell?

For example cell A1 shows 'abc12345' and I want cell A2 to show '123' (i.e. characters 4 to 6).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `=MID(A1,4,3)`

Comment: =IF(LEN(A1)>=6,MID(A1,4,3),"too short")

Answer (score 1):

```
= mid (A1, 4, 3)  would return 123
```

where **A1** is the cell with the text string.
**4** is the initial location to start getting the string
**3** is the length of the string you will get.

This is the simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

This one looks for the first numeric value and gives anything before that, press ctrl+shift+enter to run.

```
=LEFT(A1,MIN(IFERROR((MID(A1,ROW(A1:A200),1)+0)*ROW(A1:A200),FALSE))-1)
```

Hope that helps.